# C# Error Index was outside the bounds of the array (Visual Studio, Winform, .NET Framework 4.6)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, indexoutofrangeexception

I have a program which generates a key but I always get a "Index was outside the bounds of the array" exception.

My Code is this:

```
   private string generate()
        {
            try
            {
                int block = 11;
                int size = 0;
                string content = "zQzhPeWFXZG53N2tGTGlvmQzTm9UTU91NG9DNndySERrOEsveFpMQ3ExUGlo"; //this key gets normally decrypted with aes but that is not the problem

                block = Convert.ToInt32(content.Split(':')[2]);
                size = Convert.ToInt32(content.Split(':')[1]);
                content = content.Split(':')[0];

                Random r = new Random();
                char[] blocked = new char[block];

                for (int i = 0; i < block; i++)
                {
                    blocked[i] = content[r.Next(content.Length)];
                }

                string key = "";
                while (this.getValue(key, content, blocked) <= (size - (content.Length)))
                {
                    key += content[r.Next(content.Length)];
                }
                key += content[size - this.getValue(key, content, blocked)];

                key = new string(blocked) + key;
                return key;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

I think the error is in the for or in the while loop but the weir thing on it is, on my pc it is working but on my friends pc it is not working and I tried everything but I dont know how I can fit this error.

Does someone know any fix for this?

Comment: Store `r.Next(content.Length)` in a variable and check it's value during debugging.

Comment: `I think the error is in the for or in the while loop` did you debug the code? Are you sure the error is in while or for loop? Can you share a real value of content variable?

Comment: The content var is this value: rFHfC51dsfsdfUygV4MOoapJqictunjzhtgj3Tasdg9LAWSDF21XlG08I6ZhbYDz2FQmwdsExk:7567:34\n\n\n\n\

Comment: Like a this screen: http://prntscr.com/qv15zx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59986853/c-sharp-aes-decryption-is-not-working-on-few-pcs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems that you are splitting on the wrong character for your given `content` string. You can check out this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ubklbk

With your original string:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
                int block = 11;
                int size = 0;
                //string content = "zQzhPeWFXZG:5:3:2tGTGlvmQzTm9UTU91NG9DNndySERrOEsveFpMQ3ExUGlo"; //this key gets normally decrypted with aes but that is not the problem
                string content = "zQzhPeWFXZG532tGTGlvmQzTm9UTU91NG9DNndySERrOEsveFpMQ3ExUGlo"; //this key gets normally decrypted with aes but that is not the problem
                string[] split =content.Split(':');
                foreach(var item in split)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                }
                block = Convert.ToInt32(content.Split(':')[2]);
                size = Convert.ToInt32(content.Split(':')[1]);
                content = content.Split(':')[0];
                Console.WriteLine(block);
                Console.WriteLine(size);
                Console.WriteLine(content);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
zQzhPeWFXZG532tGTGlvmQzTm9UTU91NG9DNndySERrOEsveFpMQ3ExUGlo
Run-time exception (line 16): Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Stack Trace:

[System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.]
   at Program.Main() :line 16
```

In the next run, I added a `:` separator at points that returned me your field types which yielded me the following output:

```
zQzhPeWFXZG
5
3
2tGTGlvmQzTm9UTU91NG9DNndySERrOEsveFpMQ3ExUGlo
3
5
zQzhPeWFXZG
```

So basically, the problem lies in the way your are splitting your original string with the `:` separator.

Comment: The content var is this value: rFHfC51dsfsdfUygV4MOoapJqictunjzhtgj3Tasdg9LAWSDF21XlG08I6ZhbYDz2FQmwdsExk:7567:34\n\n\n\n\

Comment: @user12273309 Yes, the above string is working correctly using the above program.

Comment: That is my problem sir, it works on my pc too but on some other pc not... @Rahul Sharma

Comment: @user12273309 What do you mean by that? What is the `content` string that you are getting on the other PC. It would obviously be without the `:` separator, hence the error that you are getting.

Comment: I have to check the var from him one sec.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59986853/c-sharp-aes-decryption-is-not-working-on-few-pcs

Comment: Yes thank you, in my code is no error but now I found out where it is but there is the same thing, please look at it.

Comment: @user12273309 Okay, will take a look